# JavaScript : .Click not working (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Afternoon everyone,

I am having a bit of problem with my code, basically trying to console.log() something when I click a button. Here is the code :

```
echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  delete delete-category"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</button> 
          <input type="hidden" value="'. $car_makes['car_make_id'] .'"  name="delete[]">
      </td>'
```

As you can see I am using PHP to show the button. Button is showing up and I get my value in the hidden field.

Code :

```
$('button.delete-category').click(function(e) {
    console.log("sss");
});
```

Whenever I click the button no sort of console or any event is getting triggered.

I believe I have shared everything but if you need any more information please comment and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have jQuery included in your php/html code?

Comment: Yeah I have incuded jQuery

Comment: its work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/reydx4r9/

Comment: Guys, I got to tell that when I tried to do the same code on console on the developer mode it was working fine

Comment: However when i reload the page and click on the button no response at all

Comment: Maybe a timing problem. Try to put your js inside an `device.onready` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add a "return false;" after your console.log() otherwise the page might be submitted as soon as you click and then you wouldn't see the console output in time, second make sure your .click() binding is executed at the right time, you can add an alert('step1') before and after it to make sure it is executed and no errors hapens.

Also make sure it is execute after DOM ready, for jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  alert('step1');
  $("button.delete-category").click(function() {
    alert('step3');
    console.log("sss");
    return false;
  });
  alert('step2');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it was submitting soon as I click and wasn't seeing but it works now.

Comment: I think you were confusing <input type="button"> (which doesn't submit by default) with <button> (which always submits unless you prevent it via JS).

Comment: Why is this necessary for `type="button"`? That doesn't submit the form. Is the HTML in the question accurate?